# getStoreCategories() seems to not be working properly

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.2.1

Can this code (let's call this **Method 1**):

```
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
foreach($categories as $category) {
    [...]
}
```

be used a drop-in replacement for this (let's call this **Method 2**)?

```
$helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
$categories = $helper->getStoreCategories();
foreach($categories as $category) {
    [...]
}
```

The new theme I installed uses Method 2 to retrieve categories with which to populate the header menu. The code seems to be failing, and the header menu is empty.

Here is the relevant code:

```
public function renderCategoriesMenuHtml($momenu = FALSE, $level = 0, $outermostItemClass = '', $childrenWrapClass = '')
{
    $this->_isMomenu = $momenu;
    $activeCategories = array();
    foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $child) {
        if ($child->getIsActive()) {
            $activeCategories[] = $child;
        }
    }
    $activeCategoriesCount = count($activeCategories);
    $hasActiveCategoriesCount = ($activeCategoriesCount > 0);

    if (!$hasActiveCategoriesCount) {
        return '';
    }

    [...]
```

`$this` is of class `Novaworks_Megamenu_Block_Mainmenu_Menu` which extends `Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation`.

I've verified that the `getStoreCategories()` method exists.

I did a `var_dump $this->getStoreCategories()` and it returned a massive object of class `Varien_Data_Tree_Node_Collection` which did not contain any category names.

Any code placed inside the above `foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $child)` loop had no effect.

So because apparently `getStoreCategories()` returns a non-usable result, the `renderCategoriesMenuHtml` function returns an empty string, and the header menu is not populated.

I was able to correctly retrieve a list of categories using **Method 1** shown above, which I found by Googling.

In Method 1, `$categories` is an object of class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Collection`. Each `$category` is an object of class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Category`.

Is `Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getStoreCategories()` producing an incorrect result on my setup? Is THAT what it's actually supposed to output?

And if so, can anyone explain why `Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getStoreCategories()` doesn't work for me, since it kind of looks like the conventional way of retrieving categories?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the getStoreCategories method returns a collection of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Category_Tree` which is a collection of categories with the correct hierarchy and a limited number of attributes added like `name` and `URL`.
This would be more suited for building a menu though.

As to why it doesn't work. Make sure your flat categories are on under `System > Configuration > Catalog > Frontend` and all data should be reindexed.

Otherwise I'd suggest you start debugging in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category::getCategories` since that's where it returns some actual collections

Comment: Enabling flat categories solved my problem.

Comment: Disabling it basically breaks Magento. not too sure why its even an option. Glad it helped

Comment: For anyone reading, it is also worth noting that after enabling flat categories, using **Method 1** resulted in all categories being displayed without hierarchy, which is not acceptable. The stock method, **Method 2**, produced the correct result (i.e. subcategories appear under main categories in the form of dropdown menus). So **Method 1** is not a drop-in replacement for **Method 2**.